# What counts as points towards capturing a location in clan wars?

Tags: call-of-duty-ghosts

What counts as points towards capturing a location in clan wars in Call of Duty: Ghosts?

This doesn't seem to be documented or explained too well. Also, it doesn't seem to update consistently in the application, which is mainly why I ask.

Do wins count per person in the clan? or just per match won?

Comment: Just per match won.

Answer (score 1):

### To receive Capture Points (CP)

Your clan receives capture points when a **location** on the clan wars map is successfully captured.

The amount of capture points (CP) you receive for capturing a location is not explicitly declared and can change from clan wars to clan wars (from what I understand).

### To capture a location:

To capture a location you need to hit the minimum win threshold. For example, for something like domination it might be `120 WINS`. **You get one win-point per player per game won** in that gametype.

If another clan already holds the location/node, your wins don't count until you've "drained" the other clan's wins. Basically, each win point received by any player in any clan in your wars will count against that clan holding that location. Once it is "drained", your wins count normally again.